# Incremental backup up from a remote ftp box to a Windows server

Tags: linux, windows, backup, ftp, incremental-backup

I need to backup a website to a Windows server every week and I only have access to remote FTP. I'd like to use an incremental backup program so that I can just copy the files every week on a schedule and not worry too much about the size of the backups becoming an issue. Unfortunately, I can't find a Windows program that will automatically make incremental backups of specific FTP folders and files, as most programs are designed to backup to FTP, not from it. **Are there any applications that can do this?**

I also have a Ubuntu 10.04 box I could use to relay the site to the Windows server if I needed to run Linux programs, but I would prefer a Windows-only solution over a Linux/Windows one, and a combined Linux/Windows solution over not having it work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this:
http://www.cobiansoft.com/cbnew.htm

It allows you to download from FTP to a local folder. I't  has an 'incremental-feature'.

Comment: Yes, Cobian will work quite well - and does offer an incremental feature. I use this for backing up rackspace cloudsites to a local windows server, as seen in this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/95353/backup-solutions-for-rackspace-cloud-sites/134157#134157

Comment: Even better ;-), edited.

Comment: Site looks kind of shady. You've used this professionally before, iainlbc? The guy running it also doesn't mention the license type. (EDIT: Looks like free use, only no modding or selling). Still, if this does what I want, it could work.

Comment: I'm using this now, and it is very nice for a free backup program, and meets my needs perfectly. I really like the logfile email feature as well.

Comment: Great news! :-)

Comment: Cobian is great, full featured and free, but it can't do incremental copies on ftp (at least in v11), see the explanation:http://www.cobiansoft.se/forum/yaf_postst9_Incremental-or-differential-Always-full--What-to-check.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I do this using wget. In my case it's Linux to Linux but this should work equally well on a Windows box. While it may not be obvious from the command, this is indeed an incremental backup. The relevant line is:

```
wget -c --mirror ftp://username:password@ftpserver/ -o logfile -P destination
```

Comment: Shouldn't --timestamping be used to get an incremental backup (i.e. based on file existence and modification date)? See http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping-Usage.html#Time_002dStamping-Usage

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any windows solution that would do what you want but I am quite sure lftp has the features you need.

http://lftp.yar.ru/features.html